# How to configure multi-currency for single store in magento2?

Tags: magento2, multicurrency

I have multi-selected the allowed currency option in `Store`->`Configuration`->`Currency Setup` for single store but that currency drop-down option is not coming in front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define currency rates to make them visible in frontend

`Stores > Currency rates`

You can either change them manually or you can import currency rates from 3 available services.

By default when you open a store and see prices will be in base currency , but you can switch to others which you have defined.

Comment: Thanks @priyank it's working for me...Now it's showing in frontend